# ASP Webforms Validation control not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Please help the regex Validator is not work when I click the button .

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAddBranch" Text="Branch Name" 
                           CssClass="text-primary small" AssociatedControlID="txtBranchName" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExp1"
                          runat="server" ErrorMessage="Branch Name must be between 3 to 12 characters" 
                          ControlToValidate="txtBranchName" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]{3,12}$" ValidationGroup="grpBranch" />
                    </div>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBranchName" CssClass="form-control input-sm" ValidationGroup="grpBranch" />
                </div>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddBranch" Text="Add" CssClass="form-group-btn btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
                  OnClick="btnAddBranch_Click" ValidationGroup="grpBranch" />
            </div>
```

[image: No Error Message]

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z\s]{3,12}$ try this expresseion

Comment: When I test it looks like it is working. Can post only abc...z ABC...Z between 3 to 12 chars. Do you want it to do something else?

Comment: No errors. Even when the textbox is empty. I even changed the regex validator to a required field one, still nothing

Comment: if you put aa in the textbox and press the button you dont get the validation error?

Comment: @Idanb No I don't get any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is working perfect. As per your expression its means that a-z and A-z and 3-12 digit will accept. So when you enter only 12 in your text box the validation will be fire.

To check required field validation you need add Requirefield validation control in you code.